# Login with facebook using php and javascript sdk on captive portal

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I have problems with the captive portal. There is little to finish. My application works as follows:

- The user connects to the WiFi network and is redirected to an
  external page where he asks to login through facebook using php sdk;
- Login occurs as expected in php sdk displaying the login pages and
  everything else. Informed login the user is redirected to another
  page that receives the code and state fields in the query string;
- In this redirect page I call the sdk javascript to know customer
  data, and to my surprise, on devices that have an older OS version
  (iOS, windowsPhone or Android), when running FB.getLoginStatus (),
  the response of the function shows that the user is connected,
  however in android 7.0+ or iOS 9.0+ the user always appears as
  disconnected.

I have already lost countless nights of sleep trying to solve this without success. If anyone has an idea why this is happening I will be very grateful.

```
let statusLogin = function () {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //you are loggedin 
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            userID = response.authResponse.userID;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //loggedin but not authorized your app
            alert('User is connected on facebook nut not authorized!!');
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            alert('User is not connected on facebook!!');
        }
    });
};

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : '00XXX811XXX0000',
        status           : true,
        cookie           : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.12'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', statusLogin);
    statusLogin();
};
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Why are you switching to the client side in the first place, instead of making the API request for the user details directly in your server-side code, after you exchanged the code for a token? You’re likely dealing with a problem of 3rd-party cookie acceptance on those devices ... an issues you would not even have, if you did this server-side.

Comment: The login is done on the server side, but I need it when it returns from the server the client is still connected. On devices with older OS's this happens perfectly in newer OS's this does not happen.